# Cannot update operating system

Tags: updates, system

After a fresh install of elementary OS, I can't seem to update the operating system. After clicking the free button to update the system, error pops up saying There was an error installing Operating System updates
Too few items to process.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question with more information of the error.

Answer (score 1):

First run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` command on the terminal.

After this try system update again.

Comment: Your contribution is appreciated. Please try to make detailed answers that explains what you are doing and why you are doing to help people facing the problem understand your answer more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the Terminal application, typing in the following line and pressing Enter:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

This command updates your system much like clicking the *update all* button in the AppCentre.

If it asks if you would like to update, it should be okay to answer *yes*.

If you still get an error, it might give you some suggestions as to how to fix your system. At the very least, it should give you some additional information to continue troubleshooting.